# HTML PHP Mail Not Working

Tags: php, email

trying to do a template email for my members but when it sends via admin area I look in OutLook it just html codes, can anyone help? I think most of it is right but maybe the header is wrong?

```
$check2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$_POST[users]'");
while ($display = mysql_fetch_array($check2)) {
$id2 = $display['id'];
$name2 = $display['name'];
$username2 = $display['username'];
$email2 = $display['email'];


$subject2 = $_POST[subject];
$message2 = $_POST[message];
$from = "info@email.com";
$whofrom = "Email Newsletter";
$header = "From: ". $whofrom . " <" . $from . ">\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

        $mail_body = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'/>
</head>
<body style='margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
    <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'> 
        <tr>
            <td style='padding: 10px 0 30px 0;'>
                <table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='600' height='100' style='border: 1px solid #cccccc; border-collapse: collapse;'>
                    <tr>
                      <td align='center' bgcolor='#CCCCCC' background='http://vcasts.tv/images/bg.jpg'  style=' background-position:center; padding: 40px 0 30px 0; color: #153643; font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;'>
                            <img src='http://domain.com/images/logo.png'  />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor='#ffffff' style='padding: 40px 30px 40px 30px;'>
                            <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='color: #153643; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px;'>
                                        <b>Dear $name2</b>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='padding: 20px 0 30px 0; color: #153643; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;'><p>$message2</p>
                                    <p>================<br />
                                    Thank You,<br />

                                    Max B
                                    </p></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor='#E4E7ED' style='padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;'>
                            <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style='color: #666; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;' width='75%'>Copyright © vCasts.tv 2013 - 2014. All Rights Reserved<br/></td>
                                    <td align='right' width='25%'>
                                        <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style='font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;'>
                                                    <a href='http://www.twitter.com/ccc' target='_blank' style='color: #ffffff;'>
                                                    <img src='http://domain.com/images/tww.png' alt='Twitter' width='38' height='38' style='display: block;' border='0' />
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='font-size: 0; line-height: 0;' width='20'>&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td style='font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;'>
                                                    <a href='https://www.facebook.com/cccc' target='_blank' style='color: #ffffff;'>
                                                        <img src='http://domain.com/images/fbb.png' alt='Facebook' width='38' height='38' style='display: block;' border='0' />
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>

Sent: ".date("l jS \of F Y ", time())."";

        mail($email2, $subject2, $mail_body, $header) or die("");
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your email has been sent to: $username2!');</script>";
        }}}}}
```

Hope the above code helps.
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at your PHP logs?

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `s` for no reason.

```
$header = "From: ". $whofrom . " <" . $from . ">\r\n";
---> $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Remove the s from `$headers`, and you're fine.

Comment: Thank guys that works when I delete the s from headers!

Answer (score 0):

You are using two variables here:

```
$header = "From: ". $whofrom . " <" . $from . ">\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Try this instead:

```
$header = "From: ". $whofrom . " <" . $from . ">\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Change To

```
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```